# How can I remove data from the array when uncheck the cell in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made one sample demo.
Like selected cell print after "Done"button clicked.
It is working fine.

## Code is

```
@synthesize arrayContainer,filteredRecipes,myTableView,filtered,selectedRaw;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.arrayContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine", nil];
    self.selectedRaw = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

-(IBAction)printSelectedItem:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"The Selected Items are %@",self.selectedRaw);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(filtered == YES)
    {
        return self.filteredRecipes.count;

    }
    else
    {
        return self.arrayContainer.count;

    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(filtered == YES)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        // NSString *string = [self.selectedRaw objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.selectedRaw removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSString *temp = [self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.selectedRaw addObject:temp];
    }

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    if([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        self.filtered   = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.filtered = YES;

        self.filteredRecipes = [[NSArray alloc]init];

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];

        filteredRecipes = [self.arrayContainer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

## Question is

-> When I print selected row of table view ,Displayed in log perfectly.

-> But when I deselected those selected item it gives me n error.

Please give me solution.

My another question is when I have searched particular item (selected) it gives me selected item perfectly,then i deselect item after I have canceled searching then it gives me again selected item which I did deselect earlier.

Output image

[image]

**selected Raw**

[image]

**Unchecked second raw**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For Output image I have unchecked third line first ,then I have unchecked forth one.

Comment: its because your array content is not the same as your view (number of rows so you shouldn't use the indexpath.row as the basis for removing object at index have.

Comment: If i am not wrong you want to deselect a particular cell when you tap on it for the second time??....

Comment: Fo you want when un check the cell do you want to remove the row from the table view?

Comment: @Coder :Ya exact;y I Have unchecked when tap again on checked cell

Comment: @user3182143:-I do not want to remove cell.I just want to remove item from the selected array,and print remaining object again thank you

Comment: When you select the cell do you want to remove the item from array?

Comment: in your screen shot at printSelectedItem:(id)sender called twice before exception with 4 items then 3 items , when you called this ?

Comment: That was for print array in log file.I have put DONE button on navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So please try this.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *arrayContainer;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *filteredRecipes;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *selectedRaw;
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL filtered;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _arrayContainer = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"];
//      _arrayContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:];
    _selectedRaw = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(_filtered)
        return _filteredRecipes.count;
    else
        return _arrayContainer.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(_filtered){
        NSString *tmp = [_filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = tmp;
        if([_selectedRaw containsObject:tmp])
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else{
        NSString *tmp = [_arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = tmp;
        if([_selectedRaw containsObject:tmp])
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(self.filtered){
        if([self.selectedRaw containsObject:[self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
             [self.selectedRaw removeObjectAtIndex:[self.selectedRaw indexOfObject:[self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        }else{
            NSString *temp = [self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.selectedRaw addObject:temp];
        }
    }else{
        if([self.selectedRaw containsObject:[self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
           [self.selectedRaw removeObjectAtIndex:[self.selectedRaw indexOfObject:[self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        }else{
            NSString *temp = [self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.selectedRaw addObject:temp];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    if([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        self.filtered   = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.filtered = YES;


        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];

        _filteredRecipes = [self.arrayContainer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    _filtered = !_filtered;
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    _filtered = !_filtered;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where should i put ,I am confuse

Comment: Replace this in your method tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath... I'm working on the whole code. Give me a Minute... But at least this should help you

Comment: Thanks for post,But it is not working :),May be I was wrong

Comment: Selection process working fine,bt when i un check selected item system crashed

Comment: We can only do by maching string,Otherwise it remove as a index not matched string.

Comment: For Example:-First if i unchecked three and then i un checked four the  it is not possible to uncheck properly thank you

Comment: This codes does what you want, searching is also enabled

Comment: My requirement is:When I have select particular item for Ex. one ,two,four,three ,Ok It should be display in my log like "You have selected those vale one two four and three".Now I want to de select some item from selected one.Ex.lets un check four,

Comment: Now Four is on index three ,where three is on index four ,so it is not display perfectly .I want only selected item,Like one ,two,three(three is on index four of array).

Comment: Try my coding, you have to store the values in a seperate array calles selectedRaw. If you deselect one, you have to remove it from that array so you need a NSMutableArray to do this. You are using NSStrings, so you can check if the selectedRaw contains an object that your tableview wants to present in a new cell. Becaus of searching you have to check which array you use.

Comment: So my solution allows you to select and deselect items in a tableView. If you only want to display selected items you should implement a possibility to switch between all and only the selected items.

Comment: @hd1344 Sorry but what is wrong with my code? It works for me fine, you can select an deselect items in an tableView and you can search in the tableView. What exactly dosn't work for you?

Comment: :Sorry For Late reply,Your code is now working fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @hd1344 No Problem but would you mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Buddy,Your first part is working fine but your second part is not working.So And I communicate with other guys because i am quit near.Thanks

Comment: @hd1344 Ok no Problem but honestly? Have you copied my code and tried it fully? I did it and the selection works also if you deselect an item while searching and cancel the search.

Comment: Sorry Buddy,You have done great job,Thanks a lot,And sorry for the big mistake,Really sorry.

Comment: @hd1344 No Problem happy to hear that my code helps you

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove data based on `Object` not based on `Index` so here you can go with below code:

1st you have to check filter condition in your didselect method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(filtered == YES)
      {
          if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [self.selectedRaw removeObject:[self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

          } else {

             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
             [self.selectedRaw addObject:[self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
          }


    }
    else
    {
       if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

          [self.selectedRaw removeObject:[self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

       } else {

          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
          [self.selectedRaw addObject:[self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
       }

    }
}
```

2nd Problem solution:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(filtered == YES)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.filteredRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([selectedRaw containsObject:self.filteredRecipes[indexPath.row]] ){
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }else{
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([selectedRaw containsObject:self.arrayContainer[indexPath.row]] ){
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }else{
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Hope This will helps you.

Comment: :-Thanks a lot my first problem solved.Thanks,Can you suggest me for second issue ?

Comment: But I think Your f2nd problem is related to first one and it will automatically resolved have you check it properly ?

Comment: No need to put  if(filtered == YES) code,Just put only else part code only,Working fine.Thank you

Comment: Yes I have checked properly

Comment: let me again check

Comment: Not Working buddy.

Comment: Can you tell me same scenario agin so i can help you out?

Comment: For Example I have selected one,two,four,five,three like .Now I am searching from search bar of  selected item for ex. "Three",It gives me selected as well  as search item on table view.now at that time in deselect that selected item.Now I have canceled search ,so my all items will display on table view.Now problem is I did DESELECT three from the item which was selected.But when I did canceled searching ,It gives me Every time "first" row is "UNCHECKED",We did for "Three" but it gives me for "One",I am confuse :(

Comment: Ok Got it Please check my updated answer and update your CellForRow.

Comment: Not Working ,Same issue ,first one is getting deselect.If i do not select that first row,and then i have deselected any other item ,then no result found same selected item displayed.Thank s

Comment: Ok do one more thing after click on done searching please reload your table visible rows.

Comment: But Done event is only for print array of selected item.I canceled search using grey 'X' which is default in search bar.Thank you.When i pressed on "X" it gives me all item selected deselected items,but issue is first row "One" display deselect if i did deselect any other item.

Comment: Yes that event also you can get and in that event reload table so you will get what you want. You can get that event in this method `- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`.

Answer (score 0):

1: You have to take array with dictionary with parameter like

```
 [{
  value : “One”,
  state : “Check”
  },
  {
  value : “Two”,
  state : “UnCheck”
  }
  ]
```

then on cellForRowAtindexParth

```
 if (self.selectedRaw[indexPath.row] as !     NSDictionary).value(forKey:”state”) as! String == “Check”{
  //change to check mark
   }
  else{
  //change to UnCheck mark
  }
```

At DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
 if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

 if (arr[indexPath.row] as ! NSDictionary).value(forKey:”state”) as!          String == “Check”{
   //change state value to UnCheck
 }else{
    //change state value to Check
     }

     }
```

2:On second point you need to do same work

Comment: @Amait:-I have already done whatever you post.Output like: Two,
    "",
    Four,
    One

Comment: It gives me "",At place where I un check the cell raw. Thank you

Comment: take a Array where you can save dictionary with two parameter firstValue and second state for exp. value = One,state = check, then you can easily do this